# How to redirect between different .aspx pages using angularjs?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, aspx-user-control

I have two different aspx pages which operate using AngularJS. One page is to add a post and on clicking save, I want to redirect to the detailpage.aspx. Can this be done using AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use plain javascript to make a redirect to another server side resource:

```
window.location.href = '/detailspage.aspx';
```

By the way, is there any point of having multiple ASPX pages when using AngularJS? Usually a SPA application has a single entry point and multiple REST API endpoints that will be called by this SPA application using asynchronous requests.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using ASPX pages is a client requirement.
Is there a way to read postID from the URL; example: /details/10. How do I read 10 from the URL in Angular?

Comment: This seems to be a server side URL. Angular only deals with client side urls: the part following the fragment (`#`) identifier. If you want to use some server side parameters that are 2 possible approaches: Have the server script pass this parameter to the SPA application or use `window.location.href` (which will give you the current url) and parse it manually in Angular. It looks like due to your client's requirements you are violating some important patterns of a SPA application which will lead you to all kind of troubles. It's just against the nature of a SPA application.

Answer (score 1):

```
$location.path(YOUR_URL); or $location.url(YOUR_URL);

$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

I do use .aspx Pages as well, and use them as partials, to show their content using ajax. In my opinion you should consider going for a navigation/route provider...